# Prove that $S_n$ acts transitively on the set $A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Im trying to prove that $S_n$ acts transitively on the set $A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$.

There is a similar question posted here:[$S_n$ acting transitively on $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242812/s-n-acting-transitively-on-1-2-dots-n)

But it doesn't really answer my question as it focuses on another point.

I'm confused as to how i can prove this.
Transitivity implies that if a certain permutation maps $a\Rightarrow b$, and $b \Rightarrow c$ then $a \Rightarrow c$ is implied, if i am correct.

But doesn't this simply follow from the definition of permuting an element in a set?

Edit: Thanks guys. It seems I'm a bit tired :)

Comment: Are you working from a textbook? If so, what does it give as the definition for a transitive action?

Comment: Transitive, as in equivalence relations, is not the same thing as [transitivity for a group action](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroupAction.html).

Comment: Thank you. It seems today is not my day.   

Transitive group actions would imply there is a single orbit in the group. Since the group is acting on the entire set, and there is a permutation from each element to another in the set, there is a single group orbit. Is this sufficient proof(if ofcourse,formalized)

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, a group $G$ acts transitively on a set $X$ if for any $x,y\in X$ there is some $g\in G$ such that $g.x=y$. In other words, a transitive action is an action with one orbit.

Now, in your example it is easy. For $i,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ you can simply take the permutation $\sigma=(ij)$, it satisfies $\sigma.i=\sigma(i)=j$.

Answer (score 5):

You have conflated "[transitive action of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions)" with "[transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)".

For proving the action of $S_n$ transitive, it is sufficient to notice that $S_n$ contains the transposition $(x\ y)$ for every $x,y \in A$.  (You may want to write a few more words...)

Answer (score 4):

$G$ acts transitively on $S$ if for all $s, t \in S$, there exists $g \in G$ s.t. $g \circ s = t$.

The thing you said follows directly from the definition of a group action: if $g \circ a = b$ and $h \circ b = c$ then $c = h \circ b = h \circ (g \circ a) = (hg) \circ a$.

Proving transitivity of $S_n$ is straightforward then. Let $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$. Define $\sigma \in S_n$ by $\sigma(i) = j, \sigma(j) = i$ and $\sigma(k) = k$ for $k \ne i,j$.

Answer (score 1):

The stabilizer of $a\in A$ is $\operatorname{Stab}(a)=\{\sigma\in S_n\mid \sigma(a)=a\}$, and hence $|\operatorname{Stab}(a)|=(n-1)!$ for every $a\in A$. Therefore, by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, $|O(a)|=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}=n$ for every $a\in A$, and hence there's one orbit only, and the action is transitive.